# How can I insert parameters in the aws cli command for this cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, yaml, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

I have tried to create resources using a sample cloudformation template but it throws following error.

The command I used

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
>     --stack-name explaining-credit-decisions \
>     --template-body file://template.yaml
```

The error I got

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: 
Parameters: [SolutionPrefix] must have values
```

This is the template I used.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
  (SA0003) -
  sm-soln-explaining-credit-decisions:
  Used as root template for 'explaining credit decisions' stack.
  Version 1
Parameters:
  SolutionPrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: |
      Used to name resources created as part of this stack (and inside nested stacks too).
      Can be the same as the stack name used by AWS CloudFormation, but this field has extra
      constraints because it's used to name resources with restrictions (e.g. Amazon S3 bucket
      names cannot contain capital letters).
    AllowedPattern: '^sm-soln-explaining-[a-z0-9\-]{1,20}$'
    ConstraintDescription: Only allowed to use lowercase letters, hyphens and/or numbers. Should start with 'sm-soln-explaining-' for permission management. Should be 39 characters or less.
  CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance:
    Description: Create a SageMaker Notebook Instance as part of the stack?
    Type: String
    Default: 'true'
    AllowedValues: 
      - 'true'
      - 'false'
  SageMakerNotebookInstanceType:
    Description: |
      Amazon SageMaker Notebook instance type
    Type: String
    Default: ml.t3.medium
  StackVersion:
    Description: |
      CloudFormation Stack version.
      Use 'release' version unless you are customizing the 
      CloudFormation templates and solution artifacts.
    Type: String
    Default: release
    AllowedValues: 
      - release
      - development
Mappings: 
  SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix: 
    development: 
      Prefix: sagemaker-solutions-build
    release: 
      Prefix: sagemaker-solutions
Conditions:
  CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance: !Equals [ !Ref CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance, 'true' ]
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${SolutionPrefix}-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          -
            ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
    Metadata:
      cfn_nag:
        rules_to_suppress:
          - id: W35
            reason: Avoids user having to manually create an Amazon S3 bucket for logs.
          - id: W51
            reason: Current default access policy is sufficient.
  GlueStack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub
        - "https://${SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix}-${AWS::Region}.s3.amazonaws.com/Explaining-credit-decisions/cloudformation/glue/glue.yaml"
        - SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix:
            Fn::FindInMap: [SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix, Ref: StackVersion, Prefix]
      Parameters:
        SolutionPrefix: !Ref SolutionPrefix
        S3BucketName: !Ref S3Bucket
        SolutionsS3BucketName: !Sub
        - ${SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix}-${AWS::Region}
        - SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix:
            Fn::FindInMap: [SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix, Ref: StackVersion, Prefix]
  SageMakerStack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub
        - "https://${SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix}-${AWS::Region}.s3.amazonaws.com/Explaining-credit-decisions/cloudformation/sagemaker/sagemaker.yaml"
        - SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix:
            Fn::FindInMap: [SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix, Ref: StackVersion, Prefix]
      Parameters:
        SolutionPrefix: !Ref SolutionPrefix
        StackVersion: !Ref StackVersion
        S3BucketName: !Ref S3Bucket
        GlueDatabase: !GetAtt GlueStack.Outputs.GlueDatabase
        GlueWorkflow: !GetAtt GlueStack.Outputs.GlueWorkflow
        SolutionsS3BucketName: !Sub
          - ${SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix}-${AWS::Region}
          - SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix:
              Fn::FindInMap: [SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix, Ref: StackVersion, Prefix]
        CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance: !Ref CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance
        SageMakerNotebookInstanceType: !Ref SageMakerNotebookInstanceType
  SolutionAssistantStack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub
        - "https://${SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix}-${AWS::Region}.s3.amazonaws.com/Explaining-credit-decisions/cloudformation/solution-assistant/solution-assistant.yaml"
        - SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix:
            Fn::FindInMap: [SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix, Ref: StackVersion, Prefix]
      Parameters:
        SolutionPrefix: !Ref SolutionPrefix
        S3BucketName: !Ref S3Bucket
        SolutionsS3BucketName: !Sub
          - ${SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix}-${AWS::Region}
          - SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix:
              Fn::FindInMap: [SolutionsS3BucketNamePrefix, Ref: StackVersion, Prefix]
        ECRRepository: !GetAtt SageMakerStack.Outputs.ECRRepository
Outputs:
  AwsAccountId:
    Value: !Ref AWS::AccountId
  AwsRegion:
    Value: !Ref AWS::Region
  EcrRepository:
    Value: !GetAtt SageMakerStack.Outputs.ECRRepository
  ContainerBuildProject:
    Value: !GetAtt SageMakerStack.Outputs.ContainerBuildProject
  GlueDatabase:
    Value: !GetAtt GlueStack.Outputs.GlueDatabase
  GlueWorkflow:
    Value: !GetAtt GlueStack.Outputs.GlueWorkflow
  SolutionPrefix:
    Value: !Ref SolutionPrefix
  S3Bucket:
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket
  IamRole:
    Value: !GetAtt SageMakerStack.Outputs.SageMakerIAMRole
  SagemakerNotebookInstanceNotebooks:
    Description: URL to notebooks on the Amazon SageMaker Notebook Instance.
    Condition: CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance
    Value: !GetAtt SageMakerStack.Outputs.SageMakerNotebookInstanceNotebooks
  SagemakerMode:
    Value: !If
      - CreateSageMakerNotebookInstance
      - "NotebookInstance"
      - "Studio"
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

You need to supply values to the Cloudformation parameters via `--parameters` switch.

```
--parameters (list)

A list of Parameter structures that specify input parameters for the stack. For more information, see the Parameter data type.
(structure)
The Parameter data type.
ParameterKey -> (string)
The key associated with the parameter. If you don't specify a key and value for a particular parameter, CloudFormation uses the default value that's specified in your template.
ParameterValue -> (string)
The input value associated with the parameter.
```

Example from documentation:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack \
  --template-body file://sampletemplate.json --parameters \
ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=TestKey ParameterKey=SubnetIDs,ParameterValue=SubnetID1\\,SubnetID2
```

Comment: Thanks @Raf for your time, I tried but not working same error keep coming. I am new to cloudformation. This is the command I used  `aws cloudformation create-stack \ --stack-name explaining-credit-decisions \ --template-body file://template.yaml\ --parameters ParameterKey=instance-type,ParameterValue=ml.t3.medium\ ParameterKey=version,ParameterValue=relese`

Comment: The error message says you need to specify parameter named SolutionPrefix, so do that.

Comment: Thanks @Raf for replying to my question, I have tried few times not working. I really appreciate if you can try this repo and tell me how to troubleshoot the issue. [repo link ] (https://github.com/awslabs/sagemaker-explaining-credit-decisions)